# How to import external components in laravel 5.3 + VueJs Routes

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-router

I am using laravel 5.3 + inbuild VueJs componets.

Now I want to use routes, so I used below code which is not working.

```
const NotFound = { template: '<p>Page not found</p>' }
const Page1 = { template: '<p>home page</p>' }
const Page2 = { template: '<p>about page</p>' }
const routes = {
  '/': Page1,
  '/page2': Page2
}

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentRoute: window.location.pathname
    },
    computed: {
        ViewComponent () {
          return routes[this.currentRoute] || NotFound
        }
    },
    render (h) { return h(this.ViewComponent) }
});
```

How import `Example.vue` in place of `Page1`

I tried `require('./components/Example.vue')` but its not working please help.

Comment: What was the error when you tried `const Page1 = require('./components/Example.vue')`?

Comment: No error because gulp is not running with this code

Comment: If it's not running it throws an error, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using vue-router.

```
  const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: __dirname,
  routes: [
    { path: '/example',name: 'example', component: require('./example/example.vue') }

  ]
})
```